# Copying and renaming files on SDE connection

Tags: python, enterprise-geodatabase

I have a script that renames and copies files (feature classes) on an SDE connection. This script works just fine if the feature class name does not start with an 'S'. If the feature class name does start with an 'S', it gets removed. As you can see in the script below I use Python's `lstrip` to remove the 'SDE.' from the file name to rename it. The 'SDE.' gets added again automatically after copying. So a feature class named `HAM` would be renamed `SDE.R_HAM_QC`. If the feature class is named `STREETS` it get renamed to `SDE.R_TREETS_QC`. See how the first `S` in `STREETS` is removed? Does anyone have a possible solution?

```
    #Import modules
    import arcpy, os, sys
    from arcpy import env
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    #Set variables
    outWorkspace = "Database Connections\Connection to 10.2.5.468.sde" 
    arcpy.env.workspace = outWorkspace 
    fileName = "SDE.STREETS"

    #Describe the file name
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fileName)

    if desc.datasetType == "FeatureClass":

          #Rename and copy data if it is a feature class        
          name1 = fileName.lstrip('SDE.')
          print name1
          newName = "R_" + name1 + "_QC"
          outFile = os.path.join(outWorkspace, newName)
          arcpy.Copy_management(fileName, outFile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) off the 'SDE.' part instead?

```
>>> fc = 'SDE.whatever'
>>> fc[4:]
'whatever'
```

Comment: That was it! My files are getting renamed properly now. Thank you for the quick response, Chad.